# Apache mod_rewrite not mapping expression to parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site which uses `apache mod_rewrite` and has been working for the last 6 months with no error.

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-z\-]+)/$ /products.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

Here is the code in my page `products.php`

```
$category = $_GET['category'];

if (isset($category)) {
    // do some processing here
}
else {
    header("Location: /500.html");
    exit;
}
```

An example of a link which hits this rule is `/products/lighting-poles/`

Does anyone know why the actual rewrite is still occurring but not mapping the `([a-z\-]+)` to `category=$1`?

**Extra info**

I noticed that the `.htaccess` file on the host has commented out the line `Options +FollowSymLinks` so I first tried to re-enable this only to have the site return an apache white screen `500` error.

More from the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add a trailing slash to paths without an extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# other rules including problem rule here

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the rewrite is occurring? The products.php script is still called?

Comment: Yes, there is no 400 error, and the script still exits from products.php

Comment: You don't need to escape the hyphen in the character class. Just put it first or last, eg `[a-z-]`

Comment: @Phil Ok thanks, this obviously does not fix the error though :)

Comment: What does the rest of your `.htaccess` file look like?

Comment: @Phil Updated question to include more from .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds morbidly like a multiviews issue. Multiviews is a content-negotiation thing where if it's turned on, it'll try a few different extra things in the URL-file mapping pipeline to try to find a file that maps to a URL. Here you have a URL like `/products/blah`, yet, you have a file called `products.php`, so multiviews might try to map `products` to `/products.php/blah`. Thus bypassing the rewrite rule entirely, and you don't see the `category` parameter.

Where the options are, try adding:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: That sounds very possible so I tried to add this option to the `.htaccess` but this caused the site to display a default apache `500 error` page, do you think the `VirtualHost` does not allow overriding options? On a different note, the host applied a security patch to the server last week.

Comment: I have just modified my local version of `apache` to use the `Multiview` option (as the ISP support has gone home for the day) and I am now able to reproduce the error! I am confident you are correct and thank you for sharing your valuable knowledge.