# weird redirect behavior - request should result in 404 but sends me to page without .php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

`subdom.mydomain.com/mypage.php` is a valid file.

`subdom.mydomain.com/mypage` is **not** a directory.

When I enter `subdom.mydomain.com/mypage` the site `subdom.mydomain.com/mypage.php` is displayed... The address in the browser does not change and remains `subdom.mydomain.com/mypage`. *I would expect a 404.*

If I enter `subdom.mydomain.com/mypage.png` it does indeed display a 404 (not a custom error page - just the standard from the server).

I deleted .htaccess from the server, same thing happens.
I specify .htaccess, all it says now in there is `RewriteEngine Off`. Same thing still happens...

***What feature, that I don't remember activating, is doing my redirects/rewrites here??***

EDIT: For clarification, here's what the `$_SERVER vars say:

```
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/www/user/html/mydomain/login.php
[REQUEST_URI] => /login
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /login.php
[PHP_SELF] => /login.php
```

I visit `/login`, the browser address bar says `/login` and i see the same thing as if I were to visit `/login.php`.

EDIT again:

Does the .htaccess file only have influence on the directory it resides in and it's subdirectories? Could it be that the .htaccess file from `myotherdomain` which is next to `mydomain` interferes with this one? However I dont even remember having specified such a rewrite rule in this directory either...?

Comment: What do you get when you access mydomain.com/mypage if not a 404?

Comment: @andrew-buchan I get mypage.php O_o I added some info for clarification

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have mod_negotiation turned on, try turning off `Multiviews`:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Can do that in either vhost/server config or in the htaccess file in your document root.

- More info about content negotiation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html
- More info in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16182533/851273